# Multiple column ORDERing in ZF?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, multiple-columns

i got this code

```
        $select
            ->from(array("e" => "embarcacoes"))
            ->join(array("i" => "imagens"), 'e.id = i.barcoId')
            ->where("e.tipo = '{$this->view->tipoEmbarcacao}'")
            ->group("i.barcoId")
            ->limitPage($paginaAtual, $porPagina)
            ->order('e.prioridade DESC');
```

it works well, if i change the `->order('prioridade DESC');` line to `->order('id DESC');` it still works well, but if i try:

```
->order('prioridade DESC, id DESC'); or ->order(array('prioridade DESC','id DESC'));
```

it doesnt work. What is the correct syntax to make multiple orderign in zend framework? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got the solution,

i have to use like this

```
->order(array('e.prioridade DESC','e.id DESC'));
```

oh christ, such a beginner mistake.

Comment: Lack of specificity on the table name or alias, or potentially collision with ids, it looks like.